# Scaled Swing Graphics Causing Blurry Lines

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am rendering lines and the user can scale and translate the graphic with mouse interaction.

If you zoom out however the lines become blurry see this image:

Not scaled on the left, Scaled on the right

[image: Two lines, one not scaled, one scaled]

I believe my understanding of why this is happening is correct: It's to do with the lines lying on half pixels instead of across a whole pixel?

So how can I prevent this?

I've tried adding 0.5 to the translations along x and y. That helps but it's not perfect.

Is there perhaps a rendering hint I could apply? I'm applying the antialiasing and the pure stroke rendering hint. I believe this could be part of the issue as it causes rendering with sub-pixel accuracy but I need this otherwise rotations aren't quite aligned.

See a previous question of mine: [Graphics2D Rotation Precision Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271976/graphics2d-rotation-precision-issues)

Essentially what I *think* I need is for the lines to always be on the nearest pixel without screwing up the rotation alignment.

Comment: If you turn of antialiasing, does it still make scaled lines blurry? Antialiasing smooths things to look more pleasant, but in your case it might mess up your line in case it happens to be between pixels. Note that turning off antialiasing most likely makes other aspects on your image look worse.

Comment: @lauri That makes the lines perfect at all scales but now diagonal lines look horrid! Is there a "best of both worlds" solution?

Comment: There is one way to make image with different size look better. You render it again -- with new desired size. And add antialiasing to it (to smooth out the ugly from non-vertical and non-horizontal lines).

Comment: You could also try scaling image w/o antialiasing and then apply antialiasing to picture that was result of scaling. But the antialiasing has to be unaware of the pixel being between desired pixels. Depending on how antialiasing in your case is implemented, it could end up leaving perfect vertical lines as they are.